# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed: error: failed linking references

Tags: android, aapt2

I am running into below error from aapt2:

My enviroment is as below:

- Android Studio 3.4.1
- Gradle plugin: 3.4.1
- macOS
- `build.gradle` is as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arophix.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 0
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Error is as below:

```sh
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka com.arophix.example:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.arophix.example:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
  ~/example/example/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:95: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert (aka com.arophix.example:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert) not found.
  error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored (aka com.arophix.example:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored) not found.
  error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored (aka com.arophix.example/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored) not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi there, It means that the `Theme` you have used that is not found. `resource linking failed` means resource linking is not properly done. Just change the theme that is mention in the error. Read the `error` properly and solve this easily. This is not a complicated error. Try once you will be succeeded. If get any problem let me know.

Comment: the problem is when i run `./gradlew assembleDebug` it has no such error, but `./gradlew assembleRelease` will bring up this error.

Comment: Remove the buildToolsVersion and try adding
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

before defaultConfig section

Comment: Your error shows that it didn't get those 5 `themes` that are mention in the `error` log. Have you tried it by terminal `gradle build` if not then please try once again.

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh, Thanks! "Remove the buildToolsVersion" works. Please make it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `buildToolsVersion` and try

Answer (score 2):

Removing the buildToolsVersion did not work for me but updating my SDK tool helped me to solve the problem. First, update Android Update Build tools then change buildToolVersion to the latest one... Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32896502)